# Proving that matrix to the power multiplied by a non-zero vector are independent from same matrices to different powers

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a $n$x$n$ square matrix $B$ and $n$-length column vector $a \ne \underline{0}$, such that

\begin{align*}
B^{3}a &= \underline{0} \\
B^{2}a &\ne \underline{0}
\end{align*}

I know this must mean that
\begin{equation}
\nexists c\in\mathbb{R}, B^{3}=cB^{2}
\end{equation}

Can I therefore prove that all $B^{n}a$ are independent?

Comment: $B^na=0$ for $n\ge 3$, so how can they be independent?

Comment: How do you know this?

Answer (score 1):

We could have a situation where $B^3 = 0$ yet $B^2 \neq 0$. For instance, take $B =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $a = e_3$. Then $c = 0$ satisfies the equation $B^3 = cB^2$.

Comment: How could I prove that $B^{3}$ must equal zero?

Comment: @Squarepeg You can prove it by matrix multiplication. First compute $B^2$. This has only one nonzero entry at $(1,3)$. Then compute $B^3$. Or use the fact that $B$ is nilpotent. Any nilpotent matrix $A\in M_n(K)$ satisfies $A^n=0$ - for a proof check this site.

Comment: Hi, which site are you speaking of?

Comment: MSE I believe! But yes, the simplest thing to do is compute $B  \cdot B \cdot B$.